# Cannot find name 'localStorage'. and Cannot find name 'window'. in react when using next.js for SSR

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am struggling to use localStorage or window.localStorage in react.
Please have a look at the below code

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
localStorage.setItem(key, value)
}
```

I got the error : **Cannot find name 'localStorage'**

I have also tried with links given below but face same error :

- https://dev.to/dendekky/accessing-localstorage-in-nextjs-39he
- https://awesomereact.com/videos/Jz-zJ7lA4io

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
  {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

Comment: NextJS runs both on client and server. On the server, there is no localStorage. Is that a Server or Client code?

Comment: It's the server-side code. @Tushar

Comment: There you go, you need to move this code on the client side. Send the data in the response of a request, catch that on client and use that to set localStorage. alternatively you can also add set-cookie in your response headers and that will create a cookie for you